# Shopware show product image in invoice pdf

Tags: shopware

I have issue with showing order product images in generated pdf invoices, but they are showed in credit notes. I have invoice template(index.tpl) where the images have to be showed. The credit note template (index_gs.tpl) which extends the invoice template(index.tpl) is working.

I need some help with the following:

1. How to debug shopware requests and queries?
2. Where is the data for templates loaded?

If you need information about anything like plugins, source of templates i will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents creation goes in `Shopware_Components_Document`.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Shopware_Components_Document::assignValues::after' => 'onAfterRenderDocument',
    ];
}

public function onAfterRenderDocument(\Enlight_Hook_HookArgs $args) {
    $document = $args->getSubject();
    $view = $document->_view;
    $Order = $view->getTemplateVars('Order');
    $User = $view->getTemplateVars('User');
    $userID = $Order['_order']['userID'];
    $orderID = $Order['_order']['id'];
    $shopID = $Order['_order']['subshopID'];

    $view->assign('customVar', 'Custom Value'); // This variable will be available in document.
}
```

> How to debug shopware requests and queries?

You can use `var_dump`/`print_r` + `exit` in method above to see what you need.